# Bootstrap - Print page without breaking cards

Tags: html, css, printing, bootstrap-4

I am trying to print a simple bootstrap page using window.print(). This page looks like that (with multiples div.col-md-12 & cards) :

```
<div class="overview"> <!-- Take all screen width -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Test</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Insert some long Lorel Ipsum text here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to print this page without breaking thoses div.card. After some research, I tried multiples solutions found on StackOverflow, with no success.

```
<div class="card" style="page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-before:always;">
```

This didn't works (even if placed in an external css media print). Using thoses CSS attributes on div.col-md-12 doesn't work too.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution.

To ensure that the page-break-X works, you should be sure that your elements (and parents) are displayed as block. Adding display:block to .row, .col-md-12, .container (here, .overview) make the CSS properties works.

Comment: old but gold..!