# Prevent Page Break within Bootstrap Card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a page to be printed with 4 blocks of cards per page.
However, it doesn't break a new page after 4 blocks.
This is how it looks on print preview dialog.
[image: Print dialog box]

I have tried using page-break properties but nothing seems to work.
This is what I have tried, [Bootstrap - Print page without breaking cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024542/bootstrap-print-page-without-breaking-cards)

Below is my code.

```
<body>
<div class="page">
<div class="row d-flex">
    <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card A6card">
            

            ITEM {{ $i }}

           
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you might need to change what page size that you are printing with, a4, letter, etc, etc

Comment: Dean, I already set the page to A4 in the style

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that, the row is actually causing the page break failed. Not the card. And I solved this by override row class with !important.

```
.row {
    display:block !important;
}
```